# PacketPlayOutAnimation but only the entity ID

Tags: bukkit

I have a small "FakePlayer" that makes everything what a player did earlyer. Now I got stuck by sending to the observers a packet that tells that the "FakePlayer" should swing his arm because he placed a block (in fact I do it with Location.getBlock().setType(...);)

But now I have the problem that the [PacketPlayOutAnimation](https://github.com/Bukkit/mc-dev/blob/master/net/minecraft/server/PacketPlayOutAnimation.java) only wants to know the entity and after that it gets the ID and I can't tell the Packet an entity, because there isn't one at all... So I see there, that it has this function I don't know to use:

```
public void a(PacketDataSerializer packetdataserializer) {
    this.a = packetdataserializer.a();
    this.b = packetdataserializer.readUnsignedByte();
}
```

I know that the this.b should be 0 so how can I make such a PacketDataSerializer?

Or if there is a way much easyer way... What would it be?

EDIT:

I'm spawning the fake player with the WrapperPlayServerNamedEntitySpawn and WrapperPlayServerPlayerInfo so I really don't have an entity

Comment: Managed to get it by myself

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpigotLib for sending that packet. https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/spigotlib.5925/
After taking a look to it's source code, you should be able to code the plugin. If you need additional help, contact me on Skype: gyurixdev